# Different result on android studio emulator and real device, TextView can only setText once on every run

Tags: android, android-activity, textview

i have been trying to solve this for quite a while, i've tried it on android studio emulator and it gives correct output, but if i tried it on real device it only give the correct result on first try, then the textview just won't updated, it always shows the first result, i have to close the app and re-run it to get a different result. I moved the process to onStart() but it still gives the same problem.

```
public class IdenBiner extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_iden_biner);

    Intent intx = getIntent();
    Bitmap bmp = intx.getParcelableExtra(IdenPilih.PIX_KEY);
    String psn = intx.getStringExtra(IdenPilih.PIX_NAME);

    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtIdenBiner);

    t.setText(null);
    for (int i = 0; i < bmp.getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < bmp.getHeight(); j++) {
            int p = bmp.getPixel(i, j);
            int r = Color.red(p);
            int g = Color.green(p);
            int b = Color.blue(p);

            if(r < 127 && g < 127 && b < 127)
                t.append("1");
            else
                t.append("0");
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_iden_biner);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_iden_biner, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public int[] chrToint(char chr[]){
    int result[] = new int[chr.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < chr.length; i++) {
        if (chr[i] == 49 )
            result[i] = 1;
        else
            result[i] = 0;
    }
    return result;
}

public String arrToString(int arr[]){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        sb.append(Integer.toString(arr[i]));
    return sb.toString();
}


public String cariJenis(int id){
    BufferedReader input = null;
    File file = null;
    String fileJenis = getResources().getString(R.string.namaJenis);
    int count = -1;
    try {
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileJenis);
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
        String line;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            count++;
            if(count == id) return line;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "type not found";
}

public void bukaIdenProses(View view){
    prosesEigen(view);
}

public void prosesEigen(View view){
    BufferedReader input = null;
    File file = null;
    //Context context = getApplicationContext();
    String fileName = getResources().getString(R.string.namaFile);
    TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtIdenBiner);

    int totFV[] = null;
    int count = 0;
    List<String> tmpFV = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName);
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
        String line;
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            //Log.d("FV", line);                          //-----------FVn-------------
            count++;
            buffer.append(line);
            int fv[] = null;
            fv = chrToint(line.toCharArray());
            tmpFV.add(line);
            totFV = Eigen.addVector(fv,totFV);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Log.d("totFV", arrToString(totFV));                 //----------total FV--------------

    int RFV[] = null;
    RFV = Eigen.avgFlatVector(totFV, count);
    //Log.d("RFV",arrToString(RFV));                      //-----------RFV-------------

    String sFV[] = tmpFV.toArray(new String[tmpFV.size()]);
    int FV[][] = new int[count][];
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        FV[i] = chrToint(sFV[i].toCharArray());

    int EF[][] = new int[count][];
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        EF[i] = Eigen.subsVector(FV[i], RFV);
        //Log.d("EF", arrToString(EF[i]));                  //-----------EFn-------------
    }

    Intent intx = getIntent();
    Bitmap bmp = intx.getParcelableExtra(IdenPilih.PIX_KEY);

    int FVG[] = new int[bmp.getWidth() * bmp.getHeight()];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bmp.getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < bmp.getHeight(); j++) {
            int p = bmp.getPixel(i, j);
            int r = Color.red(p);
            int g = Color.green(p);
            int b = Color.blue(p);

            if(r < 127 && g < 127 && b < 127)
                FVG[k] = 1;
            else
                FVG[k] = 0;
            k++;
        }
    }
    //Log.d("FVG", arrToString(FVG));                         //----------FVG--------------

    int EFG[] = null;
    EFG = Eigen.subsVector(FVG, RFV);
    //Log.d("EFG", arrToString(EFG));                         //----------EFG--------------

    int ID[][] = new int[count][];
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        ID[i] = Eigen.subsVector(EF[i], EFG);
        //Log.d("ID", arrToString(ID[i]));                    //-----------IDn-------------
    }

    int JI[] = new int[count];
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        JI[i] = Eigen.arrSum(ID[i]);
        //Log.d("JI", Integer.toString(JI[i]));               //-----------JI-------------
    }

    int minId = -1;
    int tmpMin = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        if(JI[i] < tmpMin){
            tmpMin = JI[i];
            minId = i;
        }
    }
    //Log.d("MIN", Integer.toString(minId));                  //-----------minimum value------

    t.setText(null);
    t.setText("The picture pattern identified as " + cariJenis(minId));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

And here's the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.alvin.identifikasimalaria.IdenBiner"
    android:scrollIndicators="right">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lblBtnIdenProses"
        android:id="@+id/btnIdenProses"
        android:onClick="bukaIdenProses"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtIdenBiner"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Could anyone help me please.

Comment: Your appending string to Textview objecj _t_ what is intention in that ?

Comment: I append the string on object t just to build a vector, but it just for preview only

Answer (score 0):

I found that there's nothing wrong with the code. Emulator seems to have less restricted memory management that automatically reallocated everytime an activity is recreated. So, on emulator, memory allocated for an intent seems to got purged on every activity's state, but not on real device especially when dealing with big data intent.